# UILabels dont update on first load of the view.

Tags: ios, uikit, uilabel

I have `UITableview`s that set another view's `UILabel`s depending on the row selected.

On the first selection of any row, the view loads with empty labels (nothing set), as soon as I navigate back and then when I choose a row after that it loads perfectly.

Why aren't the labels being set on the first selection?

I have the following code:

```
NSLog(@"object at index 0 is %@", [tempArray2 objectAtIndex:0]);

self.categoryQuoteViewController.aLabel.text = [tempArray2 objectAtIndex:0];
self.categoryQuoteViewController.bLabel.text = [tempArray2 objectAtIndex:1];

NSLog(@"the first label is %@",self.categoryQuoteViewController.aLabel.text);
```

The first `NSLog` prints the value, then straight after setting it and printing the label's value it is `null`.

Comment: if your second NSLog gives nil for %@, then either self.categoryQuoteViewController or self.categoryQuoteViewController.aLabel must be nil. Have you checked? Just print them as %x.

Comment: just tried, it isnt nil. but self.categoryViewController.aLabel is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the view of `categoryQuoteViewController` is loaded lazily, which means none of your labels are loaded until you first display the view on the screen. So when you first access `categoryQuoteViewController.aLabel` it will be `nil`.

You can force the view to load by accessing `view` property on the view controller like this:

```
/* Force the view to load so we can set the labels */
categoryQuoteViewController.view;
```